# Writing contents from a js file into a DOM of page.

Tags: javascript

Im wondering if is possible to do a function through javascript where I will write a function to write the contents of an external JS file into an html file.

its like this:

```
    function insertInlineScript (path){
            var readScriptFromPath (path){
            return "<script>" + scriptContents + "</script>";
            }
    }
```

then ill just insert this to my page

```
    insertInlineScript("/path/to/file");
    insertInlineScript("/path/to/file_2");
```

the output of the page will be

```
    <script>
            //contents of first file
    </script>
    <script>
            //contents of 2nd file
    </script>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: To expand on @Nunners question, why not do `<script src="http://external-domain/external-path/to/file"></script>`?

Comment: i'm not sure about what you want to achieve but have you checked requireJS?

Comment: i want to embed the script from an external source so that we could save HTTP requests. currently that's my implementation but having it bundled and minified, its quite large

Comment: Doing this would not save on HTTP requests if you are calling an external file. The only way to retrieve an external file is via a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's new File API to read your file content. Here is an example using a file input, you can reuse the code and adapt it for yourself :

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e) { 
          var contents = e.target.result;
        alert( "Got the file.n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
              + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
        );  
      }
      r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

More information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=OT3rbQSX8Na).